# How to redraw a canvas in Custom View class upon clicking a Restart button

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

I've got a minesweeper app going and everything basically works fine, until I want to reset the board so I can play a new game.
I have a separate method call drawBoard() which I use to draw my board

My issue is that I want to redraw the board in its initial state with all the squares back to their original colors but I don't know a good way of implementing that upon clicking my Restart button. The canvas is in a Custom view class

Trying to call drawBoard() in my onClickListener in my Main Activity won't work, I can understand why, but trying to use OnClickListener anywhere in the Custom view class throws exceptions

I've looked around, it seems the alternative is to draw an invisible button over my existing button in my LinearLayout, is this the only way that works or is there a way to check the button is clicked then invoke drawboard()?

Update: I'm including my drawboard() as well as my clear() onDraw code

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);

```
    drawBoard(canvas);

    int sqWidth= getWidth()/ columns;
    int sqlength = getHeight()/rows;
    rect = new Rect( 0, 0, sqWidth, sqlength);

    //from the list of saved points we can utilize this to paint our squared the was we want it
    for (Point p: pointsList){


       if (Model.getInstance().getFieldContent(p.x, p.y) == Model.getInstance().mine){
           canvas.save();

           canvas.translate(p.x * sqWidth, p.y * sqlength);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, mine);
           canvas.drawBitmap(bomb, p.x, p.y, bombpaint);

           canvas.restore();

       }
        else {
           canvas.save();

           canvas.translate(p.x * sqWidth, p.y * sqlength);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, square);
           canvas.restore();

       }
    }

}

public void drawBoard(Canvas canvas) {


    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);

    canvas.drawLine(0, getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 2 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 2 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 3 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 3 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 4 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 4 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 5 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 5 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 6 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 6 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 7 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 7 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 8 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 8 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 9 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 9 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 10 * getHeight() / rows, getWidth(), 10 * getHeight() / rows, Lines);


    // 9 vertical lines
    canvas.drawLine(getWidth() / columns, 0, getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(2 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 2 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(3 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 3 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(4 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 4 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(5 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 5 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(6 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 6 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(7 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 7 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(8 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 8 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(9 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 9 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);
    canvas.drawLine(10 * getWidth() / columns, 0, 10 * getWidth() / columns, getHeight(), Lines);        //With this the squares should be drawn
}

 public void clear ()
 {
     path = new Path();
     postInvalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Could you update your questions with drawBoard() code? Maybe help

Comment: Sure, I'll update that

Comment: Shouldn't you clear your `pointsList` inside your `clear()` function?

Comment: That's what I thought but I want to do that at the click of a button, specifically, my 'Reset' button which I created for this purpose, this was my pain point because I'm aware the usual onClick listeners don't work the same way with custom view classes